# Set the fallback locale

Tags: grails, internationalization

the `<g:message code="x.y" />` tag tries to resolve the code in the message bundle with the current locale and if it can't find it, it will fall back to english as default fall back locale.

That's fine if your primary language is english. But where can I change this behaviour so that it does a fallback to a diffrent locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fallbacks to `messages.properties`, it's default messages, not english. Just fill it using your primary language, that's all

Comment: Hm. So I use message.properties for my default primary language and add a message.properties_en for english?

Comment: Yes, exactly, `messages_en.properties` for english

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the localeResolver bean in spring.

In the resources.groovy put:

```
  beans = {
     def grailsApplication = ApplicationHolder.application

     localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
        defaultLocale = new Locale(grailsApplication.config.language, grailsApplication.config.languageCulture)
        java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
     }
  }
```

And in the config.groovy configure the language properties "language" and "languageCulture".

```
  language = "es"
  languageCulture = "MX"
```

Comment: Thanx! A great answer which also shows a little bit of what's going on behind the scenes. But I still like splix's answer more because it shows me that I was stuck with my thinking...